# Ionic Push Notification with no server

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification

I would like to send the user push notifications from an Ionic app, based on an internal event (let's say a timeout for example), but all the examples that I find online show me how to get the notifications from the server.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, the plugin that you're looking for is http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/localNotification/

Just add the plugin

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git`

And take a look at this example:

```js
module.controller('MyCtrl',
  ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$ionicPlatform', '$cordovaLocalNotification',
   function($scope, $rootScope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaLocalNotification) {
  
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
    
    // ========== Scheduling
    
    $scope.scheduleSingleNotification = function () {
      $cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
        id: 1,
        title: 'Title here',
        text: 'Text here',
        data: {
          customProperty: 'custom value'
        }
      }).then(function (result) {
        // ...
      });
    };
    
    $scope.scheduleMultipleNotifications = function () {
      $cordovaLocalNotification.schedule([
        {
          id: 1,
          title: 'Title 1 here',
          text: 'Text 1 here',
          data: {
            customProperty: 'custom 1 value'
          }
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: 'Title 2 here',
          text: 'Text 2 here',
          data: {
            customProperty: 'custom 2 value'
          }
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          title: 'Title 3 here',
          text: 'Text 3 here',
          data: {
            customProperty: 'custom 3 value'
          }
        }
      ]).then(function (result) {
        // ...
      });
    };
    
    $scope.scheduleDelayedNotification = function () {
      var now = new Date().getTime();
      var _10SecondsFromNow = new Date(now + 10 * 1000);
      
      $cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
        id: 1,
        title: 'Title here',
        text: 'Text here',
        at: _10SecondsFromNow
      }).then(function (result) {
        // ...
      });
    };
    
    $scope.scheduleEveryMinuteNotification = function () {
      $cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
        id: 1,
        title: 'Title here',
        text: 'Text here',
        every: 'minute'
      }).then(function (result) {
        // ...
      });
    };
    
    // =========/ Scheduling
    
    // ========== Update
    
    $scope.updateSingleNotification = function () {
      $cordovaLocalNotification.update({
        id: 1,
        title: 'Title - UPDATED',
        text: 'Text - UPDATED'
      }).then(function (result) {
        // ...
      });
    };
    
    $scope.updateMultipleNotifications = function () {
      $cordovaLocalNotification.update([
        {
          id: 1,
          title: 'Title 1 - UPDATED',
          text: 'Text 1 - UPDATED'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: 'Title 2 - UPDATED',
          text: 'Text 2 - UPDATED'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          title: 'Title 3 - UPDATED',
          text: 'Text 3 - UPDATED'
        }
      ]).then(function (result) {
        // ...
      });
    };
    
    // =========/ Update
    
    // ========== Cancelation
    
    $scope.cancelSingleNotification = function () {
      $cordovaLocalNotification.cancel(1).then(function (result) {
        // ...
      });
    };
    
    $scope.cancelMultipleNotifications = function () {
      $cordovaLocalNotification.cancel([1, 2]).then(function (result) {
        // ...
      });
    };
    
    $scope.cancelAllNotifications = function () {
      $cordovaLocalNotification.cancelAll().then(function (result) {
        // ...
      });
    };
    
    // =========/ Cancelation
    
    // ========== Events
    
    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaLocalNotification:schedule',
    function (event, notification, state) {
      // ...
    });
    
    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaLocalNotification:trigger',
    function (event, notification, state) {
      // ...
    });
    
    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaLocalNotification:update',
    function (event, notification, state) {
      // ...
    });
    
    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaLocalNotification:clear',
    function (event, notification, state) {
      // ...
    });
    
    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaLocalNotification:clearall',
    function (event, state) {
      // ...
    });
    
    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaLocalNotification:cancel',
    function (event, notification, state) {
      // ...
    });
    
    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaLocalNotification:cancelall',
    function (event, state) {
      // ...
    });
    
    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaLocalNotification:click',
    function (event, notification, state) {
      // ...
    });
    
    // =========/ Events
    
  });
  
}]);
```

Comment: how to load dynamic data from webservice

Comment: @Nikola  i am trying to get data from database  and showing every day as notification

Comment: Please post a new question about it, comments are not meant for this. Thank you.